# Using REGEX to match elements between lines in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to use REGEX to extract quantity out of a shopping website. In the following example, I want to get "12.5 kilograms". However, the quantity within the first span is not always listed in kilograms; it could be lbs., oz., etc.

```
        <td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
                    <span>12.5 kilograms </span>
            <span> <span class="strike">$619.06</span> <span class="price">$523.91</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

The code above is only a small portion of what is actually extracted using BeautifulSoup. Whatever the page is, the quantity is always within a span and is on a new line after

```
<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
```

I've used REGEX in the past but I am far from an expert. I'd like to know how to match elements between different lines. In this case between

```
<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
```

and

```
<span> <span class="strike">
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/763505

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about parsing html with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) parsing HTML with regex. Use the tool for the job, an HTML parser, like `BeautifulSoup` - it is powerful, easy to use and it can perfectly handle your case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
                    <span>12.5 kilograms </span>
            <span> <span class="strike">$619.06</span> <span class="price">$523.91</span>
                    </span>
                </td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

print soup.td.span.text
```

prints:

```
12.5 kilograms
```

Or, if the `td` is a part of a bigger structure, find it by class and get the first span's text out of it:

```
print soup.find('td', {'class': 'size-price'}).span.text
```

UPD (handling multiple results):

```
print [td.span.text for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'size-price'})]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Some pages contain more than one sizing option, resulting in multiple `<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4"> ...`

With your code, I can print out the first sizing option appearing on the page. However, if I use
`print soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'size-price'}).span.text` I get:
`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'span'`